# React web and Native same code base separate packages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, redux, package.json

My react app is using same actions and reducer in web and native. But there are same different npm packages (for example my native app using react-navigation and web using react-router); how can I separate them? When native run only installs native lib, not the web. I am using webpack also but I can't find how can I separate them. All my libs in `package.json` and web and native using this file together. Can I separate them in `package.json` or how can I solve this issue?

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with separate *package.json* files for each project. This allows you to have dependencies which are unique to web / native. On the downside, you have to take care of keeping the shared dependencies in sync (e.g. redux).

Comment: my app folder structure like that : -mobile -shared -web -package.json . web and mobile have own package.json in their folder am i right ? can i manage this situation in webpack ?